# Only compile from .class file per source file?

Tags: java, compilation, javac

I have a directory of java files which each demonstrate one purpose.  I want to have the compactness of just these files and the resulting .class files. However, many of the files have internal classes defined which produce additional class files.  Is there a flag or some way I can limit a single java source file to produce just one class file?

Comment: The "Java source file" doesn't produce that .class, the compiler does.   No Java compiler I've ever seen provides such a feature.   A .class is just a binary blob that the classloader takes and defines a class with.   You could easily take the binary blobs from the compilation and archive them somehow and have a custom classloader load them from that blob, however.  That's totally supported.

Comment: (Such a feature would need to come along with specific semantics about where to find .class in whatever sort of persistence layer (in the default case the file system) is being used, at a minimum.  Since the filesystem is the one persistence mechanism guaranteed to exxist almost everywhere...  that's your 'lingua franca' for the compiler)

Comment: @BadZen That sounds a lot like a JAR, which doesn't even require all that  much custom code (a command-line arg to `java`/`javaw`, and different ways of loading resources in some cases)

Comment: A jar is totally one way to accomplish what I'm talking about.   As a special case of my above statement, no compiler I am aware of will package its output .class directly into a jar - you need to "archive them somehow" (eg. the 'jar' command), and a "custom classloader" (for the non-class resource corner cases), just as I say.

Comment: I think the OP is asking for a way to avoid separate class files for secondary, nested and local types. If it's just about omitting those files from the compiler output that would be unsound. If it's about creating combined class files that include secondary, nested and local types into the main type's class file: no, that's not supported by Java. All Jar based approaches only hide the multitude of class files, without actually avoiding them. In the end, however, using jar files is a valid recommendation.